# Why TypeScript complains about Array.from(somethingPotentiallyUndefined || []) statement?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typeerror

[image]

Can you help me understand the following compiler error?

When I initialize the `model` to either `undefined` or `[]` in that code, the error goes away. When I leave the `model` implicitly undefined, like in the screenshot, I get an error.

Comment: Is your compiler set to strict mode? Can you post your tsconfig?

Comment: What is `Array.from(42)` supposed to do? Why are you allowing `number`?

Comment: By the way: potential answerers would probably appreciate if you (also) provide code as text. I understand that in this case it's more about the error message, but still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't complain about `somethingPotentiallyUndefined`.

It complains about `somethingPotentiallyNumber`.

TypeScript disallows to invoke `Array.from` with a number, as in

```
Array.from(42)
```

In your case, `model` can be `GridInputSelectionModel`, which can be `GridRowId`, which in turn can be `number`, which is bad.

The error goes away if you explicitly set `model` to undefined, because the flow sensitive type inference can figure out that at that specific location `model` can be only undefined, so that the argument to `Array.from` is guaranteed to become `[]`, which, unlike a number, is valid.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! I misunderstood the `Array.from` method thinking it will wrap a value into an array, if not an array already, but clearly that's not actually how it works.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't do that. Instead, it wants to have something iterable, and then it collects its elements into an array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that GridInputSelectionModel is potentially not iterable. If you don't assing "undefined" TypeScript does not know which type model has (both would have to be iterable). Is it GridInputSelectionModel or undefined?

By assigning undefined you answer the question.

Because `undefined || []` (which you explicitly stated) is `[]`. The error goes away because "[]" is iterable. However, this has nothing to do with your model variable anymore you would always pass an empty array.